# BPM Process for User Group (keycloak)

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, jbpm

I've just integrated keycloak with jBPM. Now I can login to jBPM console with keycloak user's credentials and get related roles.

I created some User Groups in keyClock console and mapped some users along with those
User Groups in keyClock console. But I don't have any User Groups in jBPM that I mapped to my user in Keycloak console.

I have created (BPM) process with human task assigned to User Group (entered name of User Group created in Keycloak). This task was unavailable for the user that had this User Group in keycloak mapping.

How to map users to a group using keyCloak that reflects in jBPM?

Answer (score 1):

Actually a role in Keycloak is a group in jBPM.

Create roles in keyCloak (desired user groups in jBPM) and assign those roles to users.

Now processes for specified User Groups (in jBPM) will be visible to users with corresponding roles in keyCloak server.

Note : You may need to create a default role **user** in keyCloak server that will be mapped to default jBPM **user** role.